# Could not read maven project in eclipse, Access denied

Tags: eclipse, maven

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.hznt</groupId>
        <artifactId>yeahgo-dependencies-service</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>yeahgo-rest4php-service</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>

    <properties>
        ...
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
       ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.4</version>
               <!-- <version>3.3.0</version> change version, still same error-->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

i got a error in eclipse:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Could not read maven project (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar:default-jar:package)

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not read maven project
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.lambda$3(MavenImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readProject(MavenImpl.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.lambda$4(AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.loadParentHierarchy(AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.generateManifest(AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.mavenProjectChanged(AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator$1.build(AbstractMavenArchiverConfigurator.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$1(MavenBuilder.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$0(MavenBuilder.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:1024)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model
[FATAL] Non-readable POM C:\work\java\git\yeahgo-rest4php: C:\work\java\git\yeahgo-rest4php (Access denied。) @ 
 for project  at C:\work\java\git\yeahgo-rest4php
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.lambda$3(MavenImpl.java:431)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model
[FATAL] Non-readable POM C:\work\java\git\yeahgo-rest4php: C:\work\java\git\yeahgo-rest4php (Access denied。) @ 

    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelProblemCollector.newModelBuildingException(DefaultModelProblemCollector.java:197)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readModel(DefaultModelBuilder.java:687)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:303)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:267)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:173)
    ... 38 more
    pom.xml /yeahgo-rest4php-service    line 4  Maven Build Problem
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOm0v.png)

There is no problem with the project. I can execute any maven command, but there are always errors in eclipse
I tried many methods but failed to solve them. The error still appears, including:

1. Execute in eclipse, maven -> update project
2. Run as -> maven clean
3. Delete the error prompt in problems, and then it comes out again
4. Authorization directory, cmd -> cacls yeahgo-rest4php /e /g everyone:f
5. Create a new directory as Demo, copy src and pom.xml, and import them into eclipse

How do I resolve this error prompt?

There is no problem with the project itself. I run mvn clean install:

```
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.2.1:jar-no-fork (default) @ yeahgo-rest4php-service ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\work\java\git\yeahgo-rest4php\target\yeahgo-rest4php-service-2.6.4-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ yeahgo-rest4php-service ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ yeahgo-rest4php-service ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) @ yeahgo-rest4php-service ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ yeahgo-rest4php-service ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\work\java\git\yeahgo-rest4php\target\yeahgo-rest4php-service-2.6.4-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.2.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ yeahgo-rest4php-service ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ yeahgo-rest4php-service ---
[INFO] Installing C:\work\java\git\yeahgo-rest4php\target\yeahgo-rest4php-service-2.6.4-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\work\java\repository\com\hznt\yeahgo-rest4php-service\2.6.4-SNAPSHOT\yeahgo-rest4php-service-2.6.4-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\work\java\git\yeahgo-rest4php\.flattened-pom.xml to C:\work\java\repository\com\hznt\yeahgo-rest4php-service\2.6.4-SNAPSHOT\yeahgo-rest4php-service-2.6.4-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing C:\work\java\git\yeahgo-rest4php\target\yeahgo-rest4php-service-2.6.4-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to C:\work\java\repository\com\hznt\yeahgo-rest4php-service\2.6.4-SNAPSHOT\yeahgo-rest4php-service-2.6.4-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.769 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-12-09T13:15:59+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you try maven clean and maven install??

Comment: I can，it can exec any maven command，there is no problem with the project itself. It's just that eclipse always has an error prompt

Comment: You are using outdated plugin versions (https://maven.apache.org/plugins) and furthermore the information `Could not read maven project (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-p` The question is which version of Eclipse do you use?

Comment: The maven-jar-pugin:2.4 is no problem and i change version to 3.3.0, the error prompt still exists. It should not be the version of the plugin